# nginx load-balance set weight and ip_hash at the same time

Tags: nginx, load-balancing

By default the Nginx `upstream` directive uses Round-Robin to distribute requests to backend realsevers and set the weight of the server by `weight`. But I do not see any words about whether weight works for `ip_hash` too.

Some people say `weight` does not work with `ip_hash`, but I've seen examples of this in too many blogs articles to name.

#### Questions

- And what about [nginx-sticky-module](https://bitbucket.org/nginx-goodies/nginx-sticky-module-ng)?
- Distribute requests strictly with cookie-sticky and ignore weight, or `weight` DO work for the first time Nginx handles the client's request?

Answer (score 0):

From http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/load_balancing.html

> It is similarly possible to use weights with the least-connected and
>   ip-hash load balancing in the recent versions of nginx.

However, with 1.8 it does not work well for me, at least not when user accesses different domains over the same upstream.

Answer (score 0):

## Using [`sticky cookie`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#sticky_cookie)

[`sticky cookie`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#sticky_cookie) can working with `weight`

> A request that comes from a client not yet bound to a particular server is passed to the server selected by the configured balancing method.

> Further requests with this cookie will be passed to the designated server. If the designated server cannot process a request, the new server is selected as if the client has not been bound yet.

```bash
upstream backend {
    server backend1.example.com;
    server backend2.example.com;

    # srv_id is the cookie name, set domain=.your.domain.com
    sticky cookie srv_id expires=1h domain=.example.com path=/;
}
```

I think `ip_hash` is not working with `weight` (not tested yet).